# How do I set the Width property onto a TableColumn Style?

Tags: c#, styles, setter, tablecolumn

I want to change from this:

```
 <Style x:Key="ReportLabelColumn" TargetType="TableColumn">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="120px" />
 </Style>
```

To this:

```
 private Style ReportLabelColumn = new Style(typeof(TableColumn));
 ReportLabelColumn.Setters.Add(new Setter(TableColumn.WidthProperty, 120));
```

But when I try to run, I get an error saying that:

```
 {"'120' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Documents.TableColumn.Width' property on a Setter."}
```

What do I change `120` to, so that it will accept that value as `120px`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TableColumn.Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablecolumn.width.aspx) is a [`GridLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength.aspx) type property. You need to construct a `GridLength` object to set the property to.

```
ReportLabelColumn.Setters.Add(new Setter(TableColumn.WidthProperty, new GridLength(120)));
```